# Get columns values count using r-script

Tags: r, powerbi, rscript, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I want to get the count of column values for `Prod1`

```
S#  Types         Product Name
--  -----         ------------
1   ["A","B","C"] Prod1
2   ["B","C"]     Prod1
3   ["A","C"]     Prod1
4   ["Z"]         Prod2
```

I want the output for `Prod1` in this format(i.e. Count of each column value)

```
Prod1
-----
A B C
2 2 3
```

I will use this value to plot a graph.
Need a pure `r-script` way to do this without any additional libraries (cause i will use this in PowerBI).

Comment: Please provide [reproducible data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse) 
dat%>%
     group_by(Product_Name)%>%
     mutate(Types=str_extract_all(Types,"\\w"))%>%
     summarise(s=list(table(unlist(Types))))%>%
     unstack(s~Product_Name)
$Prod1

A B C 
2 2 3 

$Prod2

Z 
1
```

Using base R:

```
a=transform(dat,Types=gsub("[^,A-Za-z0-9]","",Types))
b=aggregate(Types~Product_Name,a,function(x)table(unlist(strsplit(unlist(x),","))))
unstack(rev(b))

$Prod1

A B C 
2 2 3 

$Prod2

Z 
1
```